# How to run jar using shell script and wait for its completion and then perform other task

Tags: java, shell, unix

I have to shell script which will firstly execute jar file then perform file handling after execution as that jar will be producing some output files.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question and to describe what you tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give command of executing the jar and then the processing commands. In shell, the commands are executed in sequential order.

ex:

```
java -jar directory/jarname >> output.txt
//followed by other commands
```

you can refer to this [https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159513/what-are-the-shells-control-and-redirection-operators][1]